# Number comparison with varchar columns in join query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table say table_Test which holds some test values and it has column with type varchar named say Value. Some sample values in value column are like 
'5.5', '>7.2', '>3.6' etc, only possible non numeric characters in values are '<' and '>'.

Now, there is a requirement to fetch data from this table with value greater than say 5.
I tried to convert the Value into numeric before comparison with below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_test
WHERE to_number(TRIM(translate(value,'<>',' ') ) ) >= 5
```

This query works completely fine. However when I do a self join to include other conditions in my requirement the below query fails.

```
SELECT res1.client_id,
       res1.value,
       res1.test_date
FROM table_test res1,
     table_test res2
WHERE res1.client_id = res2.client_id 
AND res1.lab_sample_source_id = 1 
AND res2.lab_sample_source_id = 2 AND res2.lab_method_id = 52 
AND to_number(TRIM(translate(res1.value,'<>',' ') ) ) >= 5 
AND to_number(TRIM(translate(res1.value,'<>',' ') ) ) < 10
```

The query fails with error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: IMO you should comment the `and to_number(...) <10` condition and run your query again. It should again raise the same error.

Comment: It means that there are other characters  apart from`><` in some of the rows. The first query  is working only for first few rows that are displayed on the screen.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear to me what you want returned.

Comment: @Kaushik There are no other characters apart from ><. otherwise first query would not have worked right?

Comment: @Gordon, I have provided sample values for value column. First query is working however same condition on a self join is not working.

Comment: Which tool are you using to see the result? It is possible that the the rows that are displayed in the screen ( first few rows ) don't have that bad data. If you scroll down fully it may throw the error. I may be wrong but it is definitely possible as I know from experience.

Comment: Oracle sql developer. I fired query to fetch all distinct values in Value column. Its assured that no other special characters are there.

Comment: What about other columns in the where clause? are they all numeric?

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression would help here. Use the [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions163.htm#SQLRF06302) function for this.

```
create table table_test
(
    value varchar2(20)
);

insert into table_test values ('>7.2');
insert into table_test values ('5.5');
insert into table_test values ('>3.6');

commit;


select
value,
regexp_replace(value,'[0-9\.]') as characters,
regexp_replace(value,'[^0-9\.]') as numbers
from table_test
where to_number(regexp_replace(value,'[^0-9\.]')) >= 5;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2ef89/1)

```
| VALUE | CHARACTERS | NUMBERS |
|-------|------------|---------|
|  >7.2 |          > |     7.2 |
|   5.5 |     (null) |     5.5 |
```

Comment: will this work for self join? for a single query, my first query is working.

Comment: As long as you match the datatypes expression (e..g number X = number Y) it should be fine. Always be explicit on data types. So use `to_number`, `to_char` or `to_date` instead of implicit data type conversion.